# ui-validate doesn't get called

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ui-bootstrap, ui-validate

I have an input element (actually a datepicker) with the following attribute:

```
ui-validate="{ customValidation: 'validateDate(vm.dob)' }"
```

In my javascript I have the following method on my scope:

```
$scope.validateDate = function(val) {
    $scope.vm.showValidation = true;
    return false;
}
```

However the `vm.showValidation` variable isn't getting updated.

Here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/poakey1/pen/NpBBXJ?editors=1010) with an example of my problem.

I'm using :-

> angular 1.6.1
>
> angular-ui-bootstrap 0.11 (old)
>
> angular-ui-validate 1.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `ui.validate` injection into your application module - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YZjjoj?editors=1010). Unless you are not able to use the `ui-validate` directive.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.validate']);
```